# Azure SaaS provisioning interval - 40 minutes

Tags: azure, provisioning, saas

Azure SaaS (eg: Workday) provisioning interval is set as default 40 minutes. Any way other than restarting the provisioning, to provision less than 40 minutes?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how the solution is being deployed, it's difficult to answer your question.  If it's being deployed using an Azure Resource Management Template, it'll be even more difficult without knowing what services are involved.

We had a circumstance where an Azure SQL Managed Instance took over two days to deploy because of an issue that Microsoft was troubleshooting over the backend.  It was a transient occurrence that wasn't repeated once Azure support resolved the backend issue.

It's probably more worthwhile to open an Azure support case to review the deployment.